# How to open openFrameworks examples on QtCreator

Tags: qt, openframeworks

I successfully set up oF on Qt creator.
However, I don't know how to open oF's "examples" on Qt.

I can find .qbs file only in 3DprimitivesExample.
Please let me know the way to open other examples.

OS:macOS Sierra
Qt：4.0.3

Answer (score 2):

Install the qt creator plugin by running the following script found in the distribution: `openFrameworks/scripts/qtcreator/install_template.sh`?

Once you do, you can import any existing project.

Please also see the tutorial video here:

http://openframeworks.cc/setup/qtcreator/

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment!    
  
Actually, I've run "install_template.sh".  
However, I don't find .qbs examples except for 3DprimitivesExample...

Comment: When you are in QTCreator, you must choose the openFrameworks template and then import an existing project (not create a new project).  The qbs project files will be generated.